# Preserved properties in Klein's Erlangen program... clarification

Tags: geometry

I have a hobby interest in math at best, but recently have been discussing the consequences of different transformations in different geometrical systems, as placed in a hierarchy by Klein's Erlangen Program:

So far, this is my understanding:

**Properties preserved after permitted transformations:**

1. Euclidean - size, ratios of lengths along line, parallelism, collinearity and ordering of points, and angles preserved
2. Affine - ratios of lengths along a line, parallelism, collinearity and ordering of points preserved
3. Projective - collinearity and ordering of points preserved
4. Topological - as a result of constraints on neighborhoods (i.e., no "tearing" of the space and only smooth/continuous transformations allowed), collinearity and ordering of points is actually preserved

My question is if this table is correct and if not, how it should be corrected. My knowledge of math is not good enough to handle detailed reasons for **why** all of these properties are preserved, so I may need a more simpler account than what would be found in a typical textbook.

In addition to all of this, where would hyperbolic and elliptic non-Euclidean geometries sit in this hierarchy and do their transformations also preserve angles and size?

Many thanks and best wishes!

**EDIT:** See comments just below this question for a clarification about what I meant by "hierarchy".

Also, it is of particular interest if it is actually true if collinearity and ordering of points along a line are preserved when looking at something from a topological point of view (i.e., the transformations that are allowed in the "game of topology" so to speak, must they preserve this property, similar to how Euclidean transformations (e.g., rotation, scaling) must preserve this property?)

Comment: I don’t see any hierarchy... are you just asking if your four things are described accurately?

Comment: I thought Klein's Erlangen Program put geometries into a hierarchy, using group theory, and it is possible to formulate that hierarchy in terms of either permitted transformations or properties preserved by those transformations. So, a geometry with less transformations (i.e., more properties that must be preserved after a transformation) sit at the top of the hierarchy (e.g., Euclidean) and those that allow more transformations at the expense of fewer properties that must be preserved sit further down (e.g., Projective). I listed them in the hierarchical order that I have seen in books before

Comment: And, yes, I am also asking if I have described things correctly.

Comment: I suppose it’s fair to call the partial order on the geometries reflecting the containment order a hierarchy.  I thought you had something else in mind. I’d rather say that the Klein program is a unifying description.  Previous to the program, I don’t think relating geometries to abstract groups was a thing.  Maybe people did it earlier, but Klein said we should bring it to the fore.

Comment: What does “preserving ratios of lengths on a line” mean? Preserving the cross-ratio?

Comment: My usage here means: 1) take points A, B, and C on a line, which have corresponding distances from an arbitrary anchor point on that line, 2) apply a permitted transformation (rotation, translation, scaling, etc.) and get the transformed points A_t, B_t, and C_t, 3) the equalities A/B = A_t/B_t, A/C = A_t/C_t, and B/C = B_t/C_t (where the lengths specified above are the values being divided) should hold if ratios of lengths along a line are preserved.

Comment: And the reason I specify three points, is that it could also be formulated as: (B - A)/(C - A) = (B_t - A_t)/(C_t - A_t), for example.

Comment: And thanks for the clarification about the Klein program. Without better terminology at hand, hierarchy was all I could come up with.

Comment: Are you looking for this? $(1/2)$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathrm{Geometry} & \mathrm{space} & \mathrm{group} & \mathrm{invariants} \\ \hline
 \mathrm{Euclidean} & \mathbb{R}^n & x \to Ax + b, A \in O(n), b \in \mathbb{R}^n  & \text{distances, angles,...} \\ \hline
 \mathrm{Similarity} &\mathbb{R}^n & x \to \lambda Ax + b, \lambda \neq 0, A \in O(n), b \in \mathbb{R}^n & \text{angles, ratios, distances,...} \\ \hline
 \mathrm{Affine} &\mathbb{R}^n & x \to Ax + b, A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R}), b \in \mathbb{R}^n & \text{parallelity, ratios of distances on a line}\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: $(2/2)$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathrm{Projective} &\mathbb{R}P^n & PGL(n+1, \mathbb{R})  & \text{incidences of points and lines, $k$-planes, cross ratios} \\ \hline
\mathrm{Hyperbolic} & H^n_{\mathrm{pr}} & PO(n,1): \text{orthogonal transformations w.r.t } \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{n,1}  & \text{hyperbolic distances and angles} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks. I assume that it is the same for elliptic geometry as it is for hyperbolic (i.e., elliptic distances and angles are invariant)?

And where did you find this table?